# How to delete multiple rows through checkboxes in php

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete multiple rows that are selected in tables when I press Delete button my code is this

index.php

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['Delete']))
{
for($i=0;$i<count($checkbox);$i++){
    $ids= $checkbox[$i];
    $query2="DELETE FROM products WHERE serialid='$ids'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
}
}
$query2="SELECT * FROM products";
$allresult = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
?>
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="Delete" value="Delete"/>
</form>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive" id="inventoryTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Serial ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Manufacturer</td>
        <td>Keys</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>Block</td>
        <td>Floor</td>
        <td>Room</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($allresult)) { ?>
   <tr>
    <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['serialid']; ?>"></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['serialid']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['manufacturer'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['licensekeys'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['categoryname'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['block'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['floor'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['room'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But whenever I select rows and press delete button nothing happens. Is there anything am I missing?

Comment: wrap the table with the `<form>` thats important

Comment: Change the design as per the standard as i have done in my code. `<form>` element structure is missing in your code..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The usage of form is entirely wrong on your HTML page. The form should appear as how i have done. Input type button is wrong you have to change to submit..

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['Delete']))
{
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['checkbox']);$i++){
    $ids= $_POST['checkbox'][$i];
    $query2="DELETE FROM products WHERE serialid='".$ids."'";
    mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
}
}
$query2="SELECT * FROM products";
$allresult = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
?>
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
<input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="Delete" value="Delete"/>
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive" id="inventoryTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Serial ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Manufacturer</td>
        <td>Keys</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>Block</td>
        <td>Floor</td>
        <td>Room</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($allresult)) { ?>
   <tr>
    <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['serialid']; ?>"></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['serialid']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['manufacturer'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['licensekeys'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['categoryname'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['block'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['floor'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['room'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

> Wrap all the details in the `<form>` element.

Comment: you have provided action `index.php` for the form ensure that all the particulars for delete are present in that page.

Comment: I did but it doesn't perform Delete

Comment: You have been missing two things. 1.) Form element misplaced in HTML and 2.) You have to get the count like this after posting the data $_POST['checkbox'];

Comment: @AlexParser. Are you still facing any issue or you have obtained the output bro..

Comment: Form isn't even submitting! Whenever I press delete button nothing happens! Doesn't even refresh!

Comment: Use this <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="Delete" value="Delete"/>

Comment: That is what I tried! It refreshes but doesn't delete!

Comment: Action where have you given.. `index.php` but you have written the code in this page itself..

Comment: If you have written the delete query in the same page you better remove the `action="index.php"` to `action=""`

Comment: After you delete all the selected values you can use `header('location: your-page.php');` and it will refresh the page after deleting. Place this after for loop closing..

Comment: Reference for header location: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

Comment: @AlexParser. Share me whether you get things done perfectly

Answer (score 1):

Close the form tag end of the table then only you can get the post value.Try like this

```
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
    <input type="button" class="btn btn-danger" name="Delete" value="Delete"/>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive" id="inventoryTable">
<thead>
<tr>
    <td>Serial ID</td>
    <td>Name</td>
    <td>Manufacturer</td>
    <td>Keys</td>
    <td>Description</td>
    <td>Category</td>
    <td>Block</td>
    <td>Floor</td>
    <td>Room</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
        <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($allresult)) { ?>
<tr>
  <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['serialid']; ?>"></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['serialid']?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['manufacturer'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['licensekeys'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['categoryname'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['block'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['floor'] ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $row['room'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
</tbody>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: I did but it doesn't perform Delete

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['Delete']))
{
$delete = $_POST['checkbox'];
foreach ($delete as $ids) {

$query2="DELETE FROM products WHERE serialid = '".$ids."'";
mysqli_query($conn,$query2) or die("Invalid query");
}
}

$query2="SELECT * FROM products";
$allresult = mysqli_query($conn,$query2);
?>
<form method="POST" action="index.php">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" name="Delete" value="Delete"/>

<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-responsive" id="inventoryTable">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Serial ID</td>
        <td>Name</td>
        <td>Manufacturer</td>
        <td>Keys</td>
        <td>Description</td>
        <td>Category</td>
        <td>Block</td>
        <td>Floor</td>
        <td>Room</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            <?php while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($allresult)) { ?>
   <tr>
    <td><input name="checkbox[]" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['serialid']; ?>"></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['serialid']?></td>
     <td><?php echo $row['name'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['manufacturer'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['licensekeys'] ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['description'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['categoryname'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['block'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['floor'] ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['room'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
    </tbody>
</table>
</form>
```